# Unable to stop duplicate ID input in file handling with c

Tags: c, file-handling

I am building a student database using c where it stores ID, name and Branch . ID should remain unique for each student and is user input.
I tried changing ID to int but it also didn't made any difference.

```
struct student
{
    char id[20];
    char name[20];
    char branch[20];
};

void insert_student()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    struct student rcd;
    fp1 = fopen("students.dat", "a+");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Students data does not exists\n");
        return;
    }
    char id[20];
    char name[20];
    char branch[20];
    printf("\nEnter Student ID: ");
    scanf("%s",id);
    getchar();
    while (fread(&rcd,sizeof(struct student),1,fp1))
    {
        if(strcmp(rcd.id,id)==0)
        {
            printf("\nStudent with ID %s already exists !\n",id);
            fclose(fp1);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("\nEnter Student Name: ");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("\nEnter Student Branch :");
    scanf("%s",branch);
    strncpy(rcd.id,id,20);
    strncpy(rcd.name,name,20);
    strncpy(rcd.branch,branch,20);
    fprintf(fp1, "Name =%s\n", rcd.name);
    fprintf(fp1, "ID: %s\n", rcd.id);
    fprintf(fp1, "Branch: %s\n", rcd.branch);
    fprintf(fp1, "-------------\n\n");
    fclose(fp1);
    return;
}
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: How many comparisons does the loop make?  Where is the file pointer positioned when you open the file in `"a+"` mode?  It is probably at EOF, so the loop doesn't read anything.  You should use `rewind(fp1);` to reposition the file to the start for reading before the loop.  You also don't write the data to the file in the format you intend to read it in.  You should be using `fwrite(&rcd, sizeof(rcd), 1, fp1);` to write the data to the file.

Comment: I tried rewind command but it didn't made any changes. Btw it should be fread because we have to only read it not to make any type of change

Comment: _Side note:_ You're replicating code with _separate_ scalar function scoped `id`, `name`, `branch` that exactly mimic your `struct`. You can do (e.g.) `struct student ask;` and then `scanf("%s",&ask.name);`, etc. Then, later, you can just do: `rcd = ask;` instead of the multiple `strncpy` calls.